# Error sending an email with VB.NET using gmail smtp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, smtp, gmail

I have a small website, there is a contact form that uses the gmail's smtp to send an email. 
here's the code:

```
Dim MyMailMessage As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()

        'From requires an instance of the MailAddress type
        MyMailMessage.From = New MailAddress("office@mydomain.com")
        MyMailMessage.To.Add("test@mydomain.com")
        MyMailMessage.Subject = "MSG"
        MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
        MyMailMessage.Body = "TEXT"
        'Create the SMTPClient object and specify the SMTP GMail server
        Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        SMTPServer.Port = 587
        SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True

        Try
            SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage)
            Return True
        Catch exx As SmtpException
            Throw exx
        End Try
```

The error i am getting is :

> 5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument  invalid, closing connection. ks5sm2862700wjb.13 - gsmtp

Comment: are the email addresses you show above the ones you are actually using?  You can get a 5.5.4 error if there is invalid syntax in the email address you are using.

Comment: no, im using normal legit email addresses.

Comment: The HELO/EHLO system tries to detect spam and block it.  The ks5sm2862700wjb.13 - gsmtp part of the message seems to indicate that gmail is blocking it because it thinks it is spam (or is suspicious).  Have you tried sending a test message with .IsBodyHtml = False?

Comment: Doesn't help.. I tried sending an email using the yahoo smtp and the same problem persists, note that everything worked fine up until yesterday (was working fine for like 1 year), I haven't changed any code, or any settings on the web server, it just came out of nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

Google just started blocking any connection which attempts a HELO/EHLO with incorrect arguments.  According to RFC 5321, there should be one argument to EHLO/HELO, and it should be the name of the machine sending the mail.

The most common broken config is not sending any argument, which is what you're doing.  The error message isn't that great in that you'd have to notice the two spaces that have your "empty" argument in the middle.

For regular mail sending, giving a hostname that matches the IP address you're sending from (ie, the DNS PTR lookup) is the most correct name to use.

For smtp-msa (ie, user/password based submission to smtp.gmail.com), that's less important, but it should still be the fully qualified domain name of the server, if it's available.

Google isn't enforcing the full requirements of RFC 5321 for this field, yet, but if you're going to fix it, it's best to do so correctly.

I don't see anything on the SmtpClient object to set what to send, so it's  either completely broken, or it is making some internal call to get the hostname which is returning an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, starting this morning.

We were setting the sender's email address as the argument for EHLO, and it was balking at that.  I believe the @ was causing the problem.  This must be a new requirement, because this worked for years.

I changed the EHLO command to "EHLO google" and it works again.

Comment: The value after EHLO should be your host and domain name, not the server you're connecting to.  EHLO is like saying "Hello, My name is xxxx".  When you say EHLO along, you're saying "Hello, .... " with no name.